# How to reload view when application becomes active after suspended?

Tags: iphone, nsuserdefaults, ios4, multitasking

When the user changes NsuserDefaults in settings on the iPhone and activates my app after it being suspended, i want to reload the active view.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could implement the [applicationDidBecomeActive:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationDidBecomeActive:) method in your application delegate, or register for the `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` notification in any other object.

Comment: Thaks I ended up registring for notification in each view.

Comment: Be aware that all objects that register the notification will get it, not only the one active. So you might be doing things for views not active!

Answer (score 0):

`- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication*)application` on the App Delegate is invoked when coming out of suspend.

Implement this method, in it check if the setting you are about has changed, find your topmost view controller and reload it's view then.

Comment: Thanks

I am updating the NSUserDefaults in - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application; is it better to do it in the method you listed?

How do i find my topmost view?

Comment: If you're using a UINavigationController you can find it by using [navController topViewController]

Comment: Great! I'm using a tabbarcontroller, but i guess something like [[tabBarController.navigationController topViewController] setNeedsDisplay]; would work? Gonna have to try that later..